# printf printing extra "D" after getchar() call

Tags: c, printf, stdio

I'm trying to work through "The C Programming Language", and I'm running into some issues with printf and the EOF character. I'm working the the mac terminal and compiling with clang.

Running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int val;
    while ((val = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d\n", val);
    /*val = 5;*/
    /*printf("hi\n");*/
    /*printf("%d\n", val);*/
    printf("%d\n", val);
}
```

works like I would expect, blocking till I enter a character then printing: `"*character code*\n10\n"`, except for `ctrl-d`, which prints "`-1"` then exits.

After uncommenting the `"val = 5;"` statement however, entering "`ctrl-d`" causes it to print: `"5D"`.

I messed around with it and found that printing val a second time (the third commented statement) will result in only `one "D": "5D\n5"`, and that printing a constant before the variables (the second commented statement) stops the "D" from appearing: `"hi\n5\n5".`

I absolutely do not want the D and if anyone could explain how to remove it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. What is your exact input?

Comment: Suggestion: `main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: Could you provide with one clear example of your code and expected behaviour? There are some inconsistencies between  your text and your code which makes it hard to follow :)

Comment: I've reproduced this. It is definitely strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what happens is the console input is printing what you type. Just like if you type the letter A, the letter A gets printed. The CTRL-D gets printed to the stdout as ^D.

If you print out 1 character, the ^ is overwritten. If you print out 2 characters, both the ^ and D are overwritten.  So, -1 overwrites it, hi overwrites it, but 1 character will not.

Comment: This is 'normal' on Mac; I'm not so sure about other systems, though I'm sure you can get it to happen on Linux too.  The `stty` setting `echoctl` controls this, I believe (check with `stty -a`).

Comment: Actually, Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) does not echo `^D` when that is the EOF.  It will echo `^A`, `^B`, etc for a number of other characters — but beware of those which have a special meaning.  Mac does echo `^D` too.